# Casablanca C++ REST SDK debug assertions fail

Tags: c++, visual-studio, rest, casablanca

I'm experimenting with Casablanca C++ REST SDK but I am stuck with this error...

[image]

Comment: 1. Give code of this "experiments", maybe someone help You 2. Use debugger

Comment: I'm new to Casablanca REST I'm currently using the code here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj950081.aspx but I'm literally getting this error with any Casablanca project I try to create.

Comment: The program is trying to delete something that is either already deleted, or something that is not on the heap at all.

Comment: Well, downgraded Casablanca to v12, the error seems gone.